# Asterisk:play mp3 sound in holiday for incoming calls

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to configure Asterisk to play a sound if it's holidays or if it's not during business hours.

After a long search her's what's i came with in Extensions.Conf:

```
exten => s,n,GotoIfTime(17:31-08:30|fri-mon|*|*?closed,1) 
exten => s,n,SetMusicOnHold(default)



[closed]
exten => 6000,1,Answer
exten => 6000,2,MusicOnHold()
exten => 6000,n,Hangup()
```

i have the following in musiconhold.conf

```
[default]
mode=files
directory=/var/lib/asterisk/mohmp3
random=yes
```

How i can achieve this?

Any reply whould be very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To play a sound, you may use the [Playback](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Playback) command.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out in our office if we get any call to our office number above working hour or on weekend, we will announce a voice that you have called on non working hours and call will be placed in queue.

The call will remain in queue with music to caller. If any employee is available they will receive it.

caller can hangup the call anytime in the queue.

These are my configuration and script which i used in our office

extensions_customs.conf

```
[Landing]
exten => 600,1,Answer()
exten => 600,2,AGI(work-time.php)
exten => 600,3,Hangup()
```

queues_additional.conf

```
[30]
announce-frequency=15
announce-holdtime=no
announce-position=yes
autofill=no
eventmemberstatus=no
eventwhencalled=no
joinempty=yes
leavewhenempty=no
maxlen=0
music=New
periodic-announce-frequency=0
queue-callswaiting=queue-callswaiting
queue-thankyou=queue-thankyou
queue-thereare=queue-thereare
queue-youarenext=queue-youarenext
reportholdtime=no
retry=1
ringinuse=no
servicelevel=60
strategy=rrmemory
timeout=15
weight=0
wrapuptime=0
member=Local/50872@from-queue/n,0,Agent 3,SIP/50872
member=Local/50873@from-queue/n,0,Agent 4,SIP/50873
member=Local/50874@from-queue/n,0,Agent 5,SIP/50874
member=Local/50875@from-queue/n,0,Agent 6,SIP/50875
member=Local/50876@from-queue/n,0,Agent 7,SIP/50876
member=Local/50877@from-queue/n,0,Agent 8,SIP/50877
member=Local/50878@from-queue/n,0,Agent 9,SIP/50878
```

work-time.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cgi -q
<?PHP
//Set time limit
set_time_limit(50);
//Include PHPAGI
require('phpagi.php');
//Development version. Set to none on production.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Create a new object
$agi = new AGI();
$agi->answer();
$tempDate = date('Y-m-d H:i');/**(Fetching data and time from running system)**/
                        $hours = date('H:i');
                        $day= date('D', strtotime( $tempDate));
                        if($hours>='09:00' && $hours<='17:30')
                        {
                            if($day=='Sat' || $day=='Sun')
                            {
                                $agi->exec('Playback','called-on-non-working');
                                $agi->exec('Queue','30');/**In queue call will not be hanged until callee hangup**/
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $agi->exec('Playback','cce');
                                $agi->exec('Queue','30');
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $agi->exec('Playback','called-on-non-working');
                            $agi->exec('Queue','30');
                        }
?>
```

If my office landline is called it will be transfered to extension 600(Landing) there i have my small script running called work-time.php

Before all i have created all extension number in a Queue(See queues_additional.conf)

now script will be executed, script checks for date and time if time is above office timing it will play a file and place the call in queue. Since no is available call will not be answered. And in queue Moh will be played

Comment: It's not clear whether this is an answer or not. Please describe how it answers the question.